# Ways of attaching a DSLR on a ACT Trail 32 backpack

Tags: backpacks, dslr

I am looking into ways of attaching my Canon 7D anywhere onto my backpack (http://www.deuter.com/US/us/hiking/act-trail-32-34432-119.html) as it will not fit inside.

It will be mounted with a lens while i keep another one inside the backpack.

Comment: IF you put it somewhere outside your backpack you probably want to make sure it is in a shock-proof bag. You can easily hit things (trees, walls...) with constructs like this.

Comment: Do you need it literally mounted to your backpack so you can take photos 'hands free', or do you really just want quick access?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are any number of ways to do this, but perhaps the simplest is to use something similar to [this belt mounting clip](http://www.miniinthebox.com/k-bm1-tripod-mount-clip-belt-mount-for-canon-nikon-slr-dslr-camera_p470630.html?currency=GBP&litb_from=paid_adwords_shopping&gclid=CJnS1NiTwr4CFcLItAodVmYAPQ) and have one of your rucksack straps fed through the belt loops:

[image]

I would suggest mounting it either on the back of your pack, and allowing the camera to hang lens down, or on the top if you have a pack wide enough to avoid it hitting your head.

Comment: ok. isn´t it a bit dangerous though if i do not see it? I mean i can understand it for putting it on a belt but a backpack? how do you imagine it working?

Comment: My recommendation would always be to have it in your pack, but if you want it on the outside this is pretty solid. I wouldn't worry about not being able to see it.

Answer (score 3):

Look a the [Peak Design Capture Camera Clip](https://peakdesignltd.com/store/capturepro). It is designed to attach to the strap of a backpack or a belt.

[image]

The clip screws on around your backpack strap, and a quick-release plate screws onto the tripod socket on your camera. Then that slides into the clip, and locks in place. So it should be easy to take the camera on or off while walking.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would not want to mount a camera on a backpack.  Sooner or later you're going to slip or bump into something and the camera is going to get hurt.

Mounted on the backpack doesn't sound like it will be easily available.  If you're not walking around ready to take a picture as the right situation arises, then put the camera in the pack.  You say it won't fit in the pack, but that doesn't make sense.  Cameras aren't that big.  What you are really saying is that you have given other stuff priority in your pack, so the camera and the other stuff don't fit together.  I see three obvious solutions: Put some of the stuff outside the pack instead of the camera, bring less stuff, or get a bigger pack.

If you are walking around and want to be ready to take a picture on short notice, then keep the camera around your neck and one shoulder.  Just around the neck would allow even quicker access, but I find it doesn't work well for hiking.  The camera bounces and swings aroun too much, and if you lean forwards it is easy to forget about the camera and have it bump into something.  Around the neck and one shoulder works much better for hiking.  Adjust the strap lengths so that the camera is against your side just above the waiste.  That is comfortable, but it won't swing like a pendulum, will not dangle much when you bend over, and it somewhat protected by your arm on that side right behind it.  It's pretty quick to grab and bring to shooting position, although not quite as quick as just around your neck.

Comment: Being trigger ready is not so much of a priority and yes you are right; I could put the camera inside and something else outside instead. Also I definetely do not want a bigger pack. I was just asking for ideas so I can avoid to do just that. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've found a few different ways to do this. Each with it's own pros and cons.

- [BlackRapid shoulder strap](http://www.blackrapid.com/products/classic)
- [Toploader chest pouch](http://www.lowepro.com/toploaderpro)
- [CottonCarrier Vest](http://buy.cottoncarrier.com/camera-carrier-vest-system-p/635rtl-s.htm)
- [CottonCarrier Strapshot](http://buy.cottoncarrier.com/cotton-carrier-strapshot-p/211cps.htm)

Personally I go between the CottonCarrier vest which offers the fastest access and the Toploader chest pouch if I'm worried about the weather. Your camera just clips into the CottonCarrier vest with a small mount that screws into the bottom. If you are doing lots of tripod work this may not be idea as your tripod won't be flush to the bottom of the camera. The pouch is the most weather proof as it comes with a small waterproof cover as well.

Comment: Thanks Ross. I had seen some of them already but I was referring more to attaching the camera on the bag.